# drop a level two column from multi index dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Consider this dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
iterables = [['bar', 'baz', 'foo'], ['one', 'two']]
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(iterables, names=['first', 'second'])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3, 6), index=['A', 'B', 'C'], columns=index)
print(df)
first        bar                 baz                 foo          
second       one       two       one       two       one       two
A      -1.954583 -1.347156 -1.117026 -1.253150  0.057197 -1.520180
B       0.253937  1.267758 -0.805287  0.337042  0.650892 -0.379811
C       0.354798 -0.835234  1.172324 -0.663353  1.145299  0.651343
```

I would like to drop 'one' from each column, while retaining other structure.
With the end result looking something like this:

```py
first        bar       baz       foo          
second       two       two       two
A      -1.347156 -1.253150 -1.520180
B       1.267758  0.337042 -0.379811
C      -0.835234 -0.663353  0.651343
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work as well:

```
df.loc[:,df.columns.get_level_values(1)!='one']
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [`drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html#pandas-dataframe-drop):

```
df.drop('one', axis=1, level=1)
```

```
first        bar       baz       foo
second       two       two       two
A       0.127419 -0.319655 -0.878161
B      -0.563335  1.193819 -0.469539
C      -1.324932 -0.550495  1.378335
```

Comment: I feel drop is better ~ :-)

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```py
print(df.loc[:, (slice(None), "two")])
```

Prints:

```
first        bar       baz       foo
second       two       two       two
A      -1.104831  0.286379  1.121148
B      -1.637677 -2.297138  0.381137
C      -1.556391  0.779042  2.316628
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`pd.IndexSlice`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.IndexSlice.html):

```
indx = pd.IndexSlice
df.loc[:, indx[:, 'two']]
```

Output:

```
first        bar       baz       foo
second       two       two       two
A       1.169699  1.434761  0.917152
B      -0.732991 -0.086613 -0.803092
C      -0.813872 -0.706504  0.227000
```